# Express-sessions not holding session data over different routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I'm using Express and Express-sessions to hold the current user's ID. When logging in, the user ID is set in the session, however, if I were to change to another page, the user ID is found to be set as undefined. Why is this?

Below is the API. The auth routes out be run whenever a page is loaded to check that the user is logged in.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const user = require('../components/user');

let sess;

router.post('/createUser', (req, res) => {
    user
        .createUser({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password,
            email: req.body.email
        })
        .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
});
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  sess = req.session;
    user
        .authenticate({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        })
        .then(({ success, user }) => {
            if (success) {res.sendStatus(200); sess.userID = user;}
            else res.sendStatus(401)
        })
});

router.post('/auth', (req, res) => {
  sess = req.session;
    if (sess.userID === undefined){
      res.redirect('/');
    }else{
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
});

router.post('/auth/logout', (req, res) => {
  sess = req.session;
  sess.userID = undefined;
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/auth/createCheck', (req, res) => {
  sess = req.session;
  console.log(sess.userID);
    if (!sess.userID === undefined){
      res.redirect('/');
    }else{
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is because I defined sess on every route, where as it should have only been defined in the login route.